# Why Widgets and not HTML?

Tags: yii

I've noticed in my development with the Yii framework that there's 
a function for many basic HTML elements (CHtml has button, link, etc.)
as well as for a menu (that could easily be replaced with a list).
My question is it considered ideal to use widgets wherever I can ?
When should I use HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, frameworks replace basic HTML with their own widgets.

In the case of a link widget, the framework might do additional stuff like automatically giving it `class="active"` if the link is to the current page, so it can be styled differently.

Answer (score 2):

One of the biggest advantages of using widgets is that you automate the `HTML` code generation, and this means more code/functionality with less coding.

For example, in `Yii` you have the `WidgetFactory` (in the config/main) where you can specify the default attributes for all your widgets. 
Changing the factory defaults changes your whole app/site widgets.

This way, you only deal with some specific view where you may need to adapt your widget behavior.

You may also hack the `Widget` code to adapt the `HTML`/`js` code generation to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Widgets are neat wrappers to their HTML equivalents. Widgets in Yii typically also load the required JavaScript libraries. For example the CMaskedTextField in Yii contains a jQuery masked input plugin which it will load together with the widget. Coding the same HTML/JavaScript equivalent will require more lines of code.