# yii when to use widgets?

Tags: php, yii

I am working in a company where I am supposed build the entire website on widgets. Like every single element should be widgets. I asked them why and they told me, code reusability. I personally am against it but they told me if I have a better approach to this situation they are welcome to take it. They want to use the same widgets over and over throughout different parts of the Yii (they are using the Yii boilerplate extensions and handle their sub applications in different servers...). So, I want to hear people's experiences and advices on this.

Thanks,
Gasim

Comment: This is likely better to "discuss" over on the http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ sister site.  There won't be a clear definitive answer to this question.

Comment: When you have to deal with medium or big scalable project, the extension and widget help your life easier (D.R.Y, less code). I've found the topic where someone could tell you more. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437783/why-widgets-and-not-html
But as @scunliffe said, programmers.stackexchange.com should be the location where you could found better answer